# Passing Query Result to a function as a parameter Kusto

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I want to create a function that allows me to pass the tabular result of a query as a parameter without specifying the table column names.

This is what I want as a result:

```
let Func = (T) {
   T
   | where Source has_any ("value")
};

let EventVar = Event | where TimeGenerated > ago(30d);

Func (EventVar);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to specify all columns in the tabular parameter schema, only those columns that you need to use inside the function.

For example, this is how your query can look like:

```
let CustomFunc = (T:(Source:string)) {
   T | where Source has_any ("value")
};

let EventVar = Event | where TimeGenerated > ago(30d);

CustomFunc(EventVar);
```

The query above will output all columns from the table `EventVar` if its rows match the condition in your function. The only requirement is that the table `EventVar` has a column of type `string` with name `Source`, and it can have any number of other columns.

It is also possible to accept any tabular schema by defining the input tabular parameter like `T:(*)`, but in this case you will not be able to reference any column names inside the function. See example 4 on [the documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/functions/user-defined-functions#examples) for reference.